# Implement case insensitive regex (?i) in grails config

Tags: regex, grails, regex-negation

I have a regex in my grails config:

```
password.regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*0123|.*1234|.*2345|.*3456|.*4567|.*5678|.*6789|.*3210|.*4321|.*5432|.*6543|.*7654|.*8765|.*9876|.*1122|.*2233|.*3344|.*4455|.*5566|.*6677|.*7788|.*8899|.*9900|.*0011|.*1100|.*qwerty)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

I'm restricting the word qwerty in the regex. I've tried to add a (?i) to make it case insensitive  .*(?i)qwerty but for some reason the case insensitive regex causes an error with the javascript that is used by the page.

Where should I place this case insensitive regex? I've also tried to escape it (?\\i) but still it causes an error with the javascript used in the page. Can someone explain why?

Comment: use `.*(?i)qwerty(?-i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use *inline regex modifiers* in JavaScript. Moreover, not every flavor let's you make a part of the pattern case-insensitive with `(?i:...)` construct. Thus, what you can do is something really limited: just use character classes to specify both case variants of each word:

```
.*[qQ][wW][eE][rR][tT][yY]
```

See [`rexegg.com` *Regex Modifiers—Turning them On*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#i) reference:

> **Inline Modifier `(?i)`**
>   In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl, Python, Java and Ruby (***but not JavaScript***), you can use the inline modifier `(?i)`, for instance in `(?i)cat`. See the section on inline modifiers for juicy details about three additional features (unavailable in Python): turning it on in mid-string, turning it off with `(?-i)`, or applying it only to the content of a non-capture group with `(?i:foo)`

Now, an alternative to using `/i` as `(?i)` is using [`XRegExp` library](http://xregexp.com/syntax/):

> When creating a regex, it's okay to include flags in a mode modifier that are also provided via the separate flags argument. For instance, `XRegExp('(?s).+', 's')` is perfectly valid.

However, it seems it is not possible to make a part of the pattern case-insensitive:

> **Compatibility with other regex flavors**: Some regex flavors support the use of multiple mode modifiers anywhere in a pattern, and allow extended syntax for unsetting flags via `(?-i)`, simultaneously setting and unsetting flags via `(?i-m)`, and enabling flags for subpatterns only via `(?i:…)`. **`XRegExp` does *not* support these extended options***.